# Problem when create a component in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

When I use my component user in a view of Ionic a received this message:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
'user' is not a known element:
1. If 'user' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of 
this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the 
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <h4>Puntos: {{data[0].points}}</h4>
  </ion-item>
  [ERROR ->]<user></user>
```

```
"): ng:///ProfileDetailsPageModule/ProfileDetailsPage.html@10:6
at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:86908:34)
at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:111096:19)
at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:121051:37)
at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:121026:23)
at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:120927:62
at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:120927:19)
at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:120797:19
at Object.then (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:86897:77)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:120796:26)
```

My user.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'user',
  templateUrl: 'user.html'
})
export class UserComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello UserComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}
```

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { UserComponent } from '../components/user/user';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    UserComponent,
  ],
  .
  .
```

In my profile-details.html I use the component like this:

```
<user></user>
```

And my structure code:

components: user -> user.html, user.scss, user.ts

I remove components.module.ts because in stackoverflow recommended this. I don't know what is my problem.

Comment: you should keep components.module.ts and need to import in app.module.ts

Comment: How, you could give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ionic there is nice concept of lazy loading by default when we create page/component.

So no need to import component in declarations array.

Don't remove components.module.ts.

Update app.module.ts like this

```
import { UserModule } from "../../user/user.module";

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        //UserComponent,
      ],
     imports: [
        UserModule
      ],
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

- create `components.module.ts` file inside components(src/components) directory.
- `declare` and `export` you components in `components.module.ts` file. In your case `UserComponent`
- `import` `ComponentsModule` into `AppModule`

**components.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [UserComponent],
    imports: [],
    exports: [UserComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [ComponentsModule],
  bootstrap: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Hope this will help you.